# Rails gives NameError for all command line methods such as generate or rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nameerror

I'm a beginner with Rails and I've been trying to find out what in the world is going wrong here for the past few days but with absolutely no luck.  I searched everywhere, but found nothing.  Basically, when I run any sort of command line method, I will get a NameError.  I have tried running this in different project directories as well that used to work.  It seems that rails is just broken...

I am running Win7-32bit using NetBeans 6.9.1 for editing files and cmd.exe for running rails console.

Everything had been working fine for about two weeks and then this started happening suddenly.  Here are a few examples:

**rails generate model:**

```
irb(main):004:0> rails generate model datatest  
NameError: undefined local variable or method `datatest' for main:Object  
from (irb):4  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'  
from script/rails:6:in `require'  
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**rails generate migration:**

```
irb(main):003:0> rails generate migration rename_password_to_hashed_password  
NameError: undefined local variable or method `rename_password_to_hashed_password' for main:Object  
from (irb):3  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'  
from script/rails:6:in `require'  
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**rake db:migrate:**

```
irb(main):005:0> rake db:migrate  
NameError: undefined local variable or method `migrate' for main:Object  
from (irb):5  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'  
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'  
from script/rails:6:in `require'  
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any sort of help would be VERY appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

These commands don't work from within irb, you have to start them directly from cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the initiative of elaborating @dhofset's answer. Basically we use rails app related commands in the console directly and not in the irb console. Even I work on windows so I give you this with few examples

This is what you do

```
1. Create new App
C:\Users\rohit>rails new_app

2. Generate a scaffold
C:\Users\rohit\new_app>ruby script\generate scaffold User name:string

3. Generate a model
C:\Users\rohit\new_app>ruby script\generate model User name:string

4. To run a rake task
C:\Users\rohit\new_app>rake db:create
C:\Users\rohit\new_app>rake db:migrate
```

Hope you have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, dhofstet has it right: these are all commands for the windows prompt, they're *not* ruby statements.