# I am using rake db:reset and it is returning an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am trying  creating user-specific posts in the seeds file. the directions I am following tell me to reset the database.  In the rails c (console) I entered:

```
    rake db:reset
```

> It gave me this error. Doesn't make sense.

```
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `reset' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rake` command is to be run from the `command line`; not from within the `rails console`.

See [Rails gives NameError for all command line methods such as generate or rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395222/rails-gives-nameerror-for-all-command-line-methods-such-as-generate-or-rake) for the same mistake.